# Springboot logging layout

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I don't understand what the numbers after logging level indicate

```
2019-03-05 10:57:51.112  INFO 45469 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
2019-03-05 10:57:51.253  INFO 45469 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-03-05 10:57:51.253  INFO 45469 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1358 ms
2019-03-05 10:57:51.698  INFO 45469 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2019-03-05 10:57:51.702  INFO 45469 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
```

For example `INFO 45469` what does `45469` indicate?

Other example

```
1857 [main] 2021-06-23T17:23:04.222+0300  INFO org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -
1856 [main] 2021-06-23T17:23:04.221+0300 DEBUG org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger -
1853 [main] 2021-06-23T17:23:04.218+0300  INFO org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger -
```

what is the purpose of the first column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the [log4j2.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2.xml#L9) in spring boot project, it seems the default pattern for the console is :

```
<Property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN">
%clr{%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN}}}{faint} %clr{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN}} %clr{${sys:PID}}{magenta} %clr{---}{faint} %clr{[%15.15t]}{faint} %clr{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} %clr{:}{faint} %m%n${sys:LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD}
</Property>
```

So the number should indicates the PID, so the ID of the process which runs your app.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I never used the default format (for my own logs, yours are the startup logs). My first thing is to replace it whith my configuration. It looks and based on [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) it should be the [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) (process ID).